# How can I work out days, hours and minutes from a total number of minuts?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel I have a number of minutes that I need to convert in to days, hours and minutes, but I cannot figure out how to get the minutes. Here is how the data must be presented -

```
Total Minutes   Days    Hours   Minutes
173,120         120     5       ?
131,870         91      13      ?
```

Can anyone please suggest the formula I could use to work out he minutes?

Here are the formulas I am using for days and hours -

```
Days = ROUNDDOWN((TotalsTable[[#This Row],[Total Minutes]]/60)/24, 0)
Hours = ROUNDDOWN(MOD(TotalsTable[[#This Row],[Total Minutes]]/60, 24), 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way seems to be just to undo essentially what you have done for the days, and subract that from Total Minutes:

```
=[Total Minutes]-(([Hours]*60)+([Days]*24*60))
```

On your examples it gives:

```
173120  120 5   20
131870  91  13  50
```

Disclaimer, I just used cells directly, where A1 was total minutes, B1 Days, C1 Hours, D1 minutes. This is the actual formula from D1:

```
=(A1)-((C1*60)+(B1*24*60))
```

The alternative would be to nest many MOD operations, which I think is less readable.

Comment: Oh, seem I was too late to type...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Days = ROUNDDOWN([@[total min]]/60/24, 0)
Hours = ROUNDDOWN([@[total min]]/60-[@days]*24, 0)
Minutes = ROUNDDOWN([@[total min]]-[@days]*24*60-[@hours]*60, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer: I'm using Google Sheets rather than Excel, so some details may differ, though their capabilities are broadly similar.)*

Do hours and minutes *have* to be separate cells, or merely separately *readable*?

For example, one could scale the hours & minutes to be a fraction of a day, and then format that using a custom time format such as `h"h"m"m"`. (Unfortunately extending this

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **minutes** | *hide this column* | **days** | **hours & minutes** |
| 2 | 1234567 | `=A2/1440` | `=trunc(B2,0)` | `=B2-C2` |

Then format:

- column B hidden (zero width);
- column C with custom format `# "days"`; and
- column D with custom format `[H] "hours" M "minutes"`.

I've used `trunc` rather than `rounddown` because it copes better with negative times: if you have, say, *minus* 1800 minutes, you'd want that shown as `-1 days -6 hours` rather than `-2 days 18 hours`.

(PS: Using `[H]` rather than just `H` indicates that hours count a duration rather than being a time of day.)